# Why can I mov into eax, into ax, but not into al, or even maybe into ah?

Tags: c++, assembly

If I `mov, eax 12345` and later `mov var, eax` (assuming var is a 32bit int etc..etc..) and output `var` later it'll output correctly.

Same with `ax`. `mov ax, 65535` -> `mov var16, ax` will output correctly.

But if I `mov` into `al` or even `ah` it won't output anything.

Perhaps moving into `ah` not working makes sense. But why is that so for both?

```
typedef int int32;
typedef unsigned char int8;
typedef short int16;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int8  c1 = 0;
    int8  c2 = 0;
    __asm
    {
        mov al, 255
        mov c1, al
    }

    cout << c1 << endl; //outputs nothing, same if I used ah

    //whereas

    int32 n = 0;
    __asm 
    {
        mov eax, 10000
        mov n, eax
    }

    cout << n << endl; // works fine, well, you get the picture

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 8 bit unsigned byte has max value of 255 (zero based).

Comment: Note that 256 is too large for an 8 bit variable.

Comment: You have the same range error with `AX`. A `WORD` has a range of 0..65535 and _not_ 65536.

Comment: Ok, edited to zero based, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not (only) with your assembly code, it's the way you print your value:

```
cout << c1 << endl;
```

Even though c1 is unsigned char (aka uint8), C++ iostreams treat it the same way they treat an ordinary char. In other words, that code is roughly equivalent to:

```
printf("%c\n", c1);
```

Just cast it to unsigned int and it should work fine.

BTW, on some platforms (e.g. Linux PowerPC) the ordinary char is actually unsigned.

Comment: will `cout` print an `unsigned char` as a character or as a number?

Comment: @Asu: As a character... you need to cast it to an int (or use something other than the cout streaming operator): `std::cout << (int) c;`

Comment: Oh, so I CAN mov into the registers, it's just a case of data interpretation on the output

Comment: You can use `cout << +c1` to cast it to int

Answer (score 0):

`256` equals to `2^8`

when you use `int8` , it uses twos complement approach , so the number is between `[-128 , 127]`

I think if you change its type to **unsigned** **integer** , it must work

Comment: unsigned int is 32bit, you can't move the value of an 8bit register into a 32bit integer. error C2443: operand size conflict